# Routerlink in a routerling - Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Is it possible to have a `routerLink` in a `div` that contains another `div` with a `routerLink`?

```
 <div [routerLink]="xy">
    <span [routerLink]="yx">clickable Link</span>
 </div>
```

The problem is, that it first redirects you to the first `routerLink` in the `div` and then to the `routerLink` in the span, if you click the text in the span. It should only redirect to the span's link. I already tried to add to the span, but without success:

```
(click)="stop($event)"

stop(event: Event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO jack. If you are making clickable DIVs or SPANs please also ensure they are accessible by ensuring they are tabbable and have an ARIA role (or better yet use an anchor element so they are intrinsically accessible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have some content/width/height in order to make the div & span clickable

```
<div routerLink="/one">
   one
   <span routerLink="/two" (click)="stop($event)">two</span>
</div>
```

In the component.ts file

```
stop(e: Event) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}
```